# inherit class in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance

i have a class like this

```
Partial Class main 

end class
```

in that i have method

e.g.

```
Partial Class main 

sub loadreport

end sub

end class
```

in that i use html controls and asp controls also call store procedure
and there is button on that page

```
  <asp:Button ID="go" runat="server" CssClass="btn1" Width="80px" />
```

now when  i click on button then data is displayed on Main page

Next i try to call employeeform.aspx on that button click and want that all data in employee form

for this i do this

```
 <asp:Button ID="pb_go" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('employeeform.aspx', 'OtherPage');" CssClass="btn1" Width="80px" />
```

when i click on button then now employeform.aspx page is open and here i try to get all data which is main page and want to displayed in employeeform.aspx page

and for this i try to call loadreport method on employeeform.aspx form through inherit

```
 Partial Class employeeform
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    end class
```

but i unable to call main class in that employeeform

how i do this ?

Comment: what has this to do with c#?

Comment: _" want that all data in employee form"_  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. But server side code can't access client side forms. The loading will have to be done on the Load event of employeeform.aspx and not on the click of pb_GetReport

Comment: check update question please @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

Your employee form would need, to inherit from Main. Normally you will have a base page, with common logic in it for a specific module. You may also consider looking at master pages.
Example:
public partial class EmployeePage: BasePage

Comment: yes i try to call that way but i unable to call main page in employeeform page.. Main page is not appear in instantiate list